# Jquery get HTML Table column's text in array

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, fusioncharts

Edit :
I have an HTML table like in the picture below, and now i need to make the chart with the same code we used last time ( remember we have to write a jquery code to select data).

The chart i need this time is a timeline chart. (with time selected in column 4 and colum 9 ) and for each type (Pink/Blue/Green..) a line chart with sum amount capitalised by time.

Example: 
For green Catégorie a line representative for that

- In 12/12/2012 : 8000 $
- In 13/12/2012 : 8000 $ + 1000 $

Code :

```
  <script>             
 function getData(columnOrder, keyName) {
 var obj, table = $('table'), array = [];
 table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
 var rows = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + columnOrder +')');
 rows.each(function(){
    obj = {};
    obj[keyName] = $(this).text();
    array.push(obj);
 });
 });
 return array;
 }

 var Time= getData(4, 'time');
 var datasline1 = getData(5, 'value');
 var datasline2 = getData(5, 'value');
 var datasline3 = getData(5, 'value');
 var datasline4 = getData(5, 'value');


 console.log(Time);
 console.log(datas1/2/3/4);


 $("#chart-container").insertFusionCharts({
 type: "mscombi2d",
 width: "100%",
 height: "40%",
 dataFormat: "json",
 dataSource: {
 "chart": {
 "caption": "Balance Perfomance",

 "exportenabled": "1",
 "theme": "fusion"
 },
 "Time": [
 {
  "Time": Time
  }
 ],
 "dataset": [
 {
  "seriesname": "Line1",
     "renderas": "line",
  "showanchors": "1",
  "data": datasline1
  },
  {
  "seriesname": "Line2",
     "renderas": "line",
  "showanchors": "1",
  "data": datasline2
  },
  ] 
  }
  });

        </script>
```

[image]

Edit 2 : My console Errors
[image]

Comment: Really i didn't understand about what you want. Where is your data? and what can we do for you?

Comment: My data is my html table in my view

Comment: Can you share example categories and dataset array?

Comment: yes, {
          "label": "East"
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two function for you. One is grouping data by date and second preparing data for the chart. It's a bit complicated but that's not true way. You should make data manipulation on server side.

And i used data-value for `td` to get values easily. You use different elements like `<span>` in `td` element so get data from data-value attr is better choice i think.

[jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQyaVg?editors=0010)

```
function groupDataByDate() {
   var columns, columnOrder, data,
       table = $('table'), mainObj = {};

   columns = [
    {
      title: 'date',
      values: [4,9]
    },
    {
      title: 'element',
      values: [1,6]
    },
    {
      title: 'value',
      values: [5,10]
    }
  ];

   table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
     data = {};
     for(i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
       text = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + columns[i].values[0] +')').data('value');
       if (!text) {
         text = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + columns[i].values[1] +')').data('value');
       }

       data[columns[i].title] = text;
     }

     if (!mainObj[data.date]) {
       mainObj[data.date] = [];
     }
       mainObj[data.date].push(data);
   });

  // convert to array from object
   return $.map(mainObj, function(value, index) {
       return [value];
   });
}

function getData(data, type) {
  var arr = [], mainObj = {};
  if (type === 'dates') {

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      arr.push({ label: data[i][0].date })
    }

    return arr;
  }

  var subObj = {
      invoice: { value: 0 },
      pettycash: { value: 0 },
      tocash: { value: 0 },
      bankentry: { value: 0 },
  };

  for(index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {

    // sum with previous dates
    for(i = 0; i < data[index].length; i++) {
      subObj[data[index][i].element].value += Number(data[index][i].value);
    }

    arr.push(Object.assign({},{
      invoice: Object.assign({}, subObj.invoice),
      pettycash: Object.assign({}, subObj.pettycash),
      tocash: Object.assign({}, subObj.tocash),
      bankentry: Object.assign({}, subObj.bankentry)
    }));
  }

  return arr;
}

var groupedData = groupDataByDate();
var categoryDatas = getData(groupedData, 'dates');
var valueDatas = getData(groupedData, 'values');

const dataSource = {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Reach of Social Media Platforms amoung youth",
    "yaxisname": "% of youth on this platform",
    "subcaption": "2012-2016",
    "showhovereffect": "1",
    "numbersuffix": "$",
    "drawcrossline": "1",
    "plottooltext": "<b>$dataValue</b> of youth were on $seriesName",
    "theme": "fusion"
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "category": categoryDatas
    }
  ],
  "dataset": [
    {
      "seriesname": "Invoice",
      "data": valueDatas.map(function(item){
        return item.invoice
      })
    },
    {
      "seriesname": "PettyCash",
      "data": valueDatas.map(function(item){
        return item.pettycash
      })
    },
    {
      "seriesname": "To Cash",
      "data": valueDatas.map(function(item){
        return item.tocash
      })
    },
    {
      "seriesname": "BankEntry",
      "data": valueDatas.map(function(item){
        return item.bankentry
      })
    }
  ]
};

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
   var myChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: "msline",
      renderAt: "chart-container",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource
   }).render();
});
```

Comment: Thaaaaank you very much, it works, i just need an update please, can you check my eddited post ? Thank you sir..

Comment: categories = accounts and values = costs in your chart? is it true?

Comment: Hello Sir, hope you are doing well. Can you help me again with a new graph ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you again Sir !  I eddited post for you, hope you understand me

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't edit your question for new. You should have opened a new question. And about your question, I guess you want to create a new line chart? Can you share line chart codes with example data of each type?

Comment: yes Sir, i eddited post for you. the full code of the Chart with multiple lines dataset and render in example.

Comment: But in my case, the data line and the amount may be in column 4 or 9 depent on if it's in cash or bank

Comment: Ok, I understand you but can you give me a running sample? I can not see the graph which you want. Include HTML table, and example data please maybe on JSfiddle. Don't use getData() function. Maybe we might change this function to get data easily. It's more complex chart i guess.

Comment: Exactly something like this one : https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/line-area-charts/line-chart-with-multiple-series 
4 Lines, each for for each Category with time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183984/discussion-between-guvenakcbn-and-yassine-j).